# JSON Array into JS Object Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I really hate 'do this for me' questions but I am at a complete loss. I think I just don't get JSON. So here's an example of my JSON:

```
"max":"10",
"min":"0",
"attributes":[
    {
        "attributeName":"Fortitude",
        "attributeColor":"#B7B7B7"
    },
    {
        "attributeName":"Vigor",
        "attributeColor":"#D5A6BD"
    },
    {
        "attributeName":"Celerity",
        "attributeColor":"#B4A7D6"
    }
]
```

It's external and I want to grab it, and then set a js variable to act as an array of attribute objects.  So if in JS I set:

```
 var attributes = [];
 attributes = whatEverNeedsToGoHere;
```

And then I loop over that variable I could do something like:

```
console.log(attributes[0].attributeName);
```

And get "Fortitude". I understand how to get the JSON with jQuery using  $.getJSON(); But I don't know get what needs to happen to turn the attributes array into an array of objects.

UPDATE: How I'm calling the JSON in right now.

```
var attributesData = $.getJSON("jsonDB/attributes.js", function(data){

        var thisAttribute = {"attributeName":String(data[i].attributeName),"attributeColor":String(data[i].attributeColor)};
        attributes.push(thisAttribute);
        console.log(attributes.attributeName);

});
```

Comment: "It's external and I want to grab it" - Where is your ajax call that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you are after:

```
var attributes;

$.getJSON("jsonDB/attributes.js", function(data){
  attributes = data.attributes;
  console.log(attributes);
});
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7xhzas9y/). I have stubbed `getJSON` for this purpose:

```js
function getJSON(url, callbackfn){
  var data = {
    "max":"10",
    "min":"0",
    "attributes":[
      {
        "attributeName":"Fortitude",
        "attributeColor":"#B7B7B7"
      },
      {
        "attributeName":"Vigor",
        "attributeColor":"#D5A6BD"
      },
      {
        "attributeName":"Celerity",
        "attributeColor":"#B4A7D6"
      }
    ]
  }

  callbackfn(data);
}

var attributes;

getJSON("jsonDB/attributes.js", function(data){
  attributes = data.attributes;
  console.log(attributes);
});
```

Comment: I KNEW IT HAD TO BE THAT SIMPLE. Seamus... I... I love you.

Answer (score 1):

Using the open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com) you could do it like this in one line

```js
var data = {"max":"10",
"min":"0",
"attributes":[
    {
        "attributeName":"Fortitude",
        "attributeColor":"#B7B7B7"
    },
    {
        "attributeName":"Vigor",
        "attributeColor":"#D5A6BD"
    },
    {
        "attributeName":"Celerity",
        "attributeColor":"#B4A7D6"
    }
]
}

var result = jinqJs().from(data).select('attributes');

document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/fordth/jinqJs/master/jinqjs.js"></script>
```

.

```
var attributes = jinqJs().from('http://..some json url').select('attributes');
```

This will return a collection of the following:

```
[
        {
            "attributeName":"Fortitude",
            "attributeColor":"#B7B7B7"
        },
        {
            "attributeName":"Vigor",
            "attributeColor":"#D5A6BD"
        },
        {
            "attributeName":"Celerity",
            "attributeColor":"#B4A7D6"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSon data is invalid.

The proper format for this data being set as Json is the following:

```
{
    "max": "10",
    "min": "0",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "attributeName": "Fortitude",
            "attributeColor": "#B7B7B7"
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "Vigor",
            "attributeColor": "#D5A6BD"
        },
        {
            "attributeName": "Celerity",
            "attributeColor": "#B4A7D6"
        }
    ]
}
```

And, in this situation, I do highly advice to use [Jspath](https://github.com/dfilatov/jspath). Jspath allows you to perform XPath expressions on JSon data.

Comment: I'll look into that, it kind of reminds me of a Query engine for JSON. But is there no native way to do this in JS or jQuery?

Comment: Seriously an entire library for this small of a JSON packet?